# Reloading gunicorn worker which takes long time to load

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, kill, application-restart

I have a Nginx+Gunicorn+Flask application which provides some APIs using a machine learning model. The model is stored in a large file and takes long time (about one minute) to be loaded into memory.
Now I want to update the model file and restart the worker without downtime. How can I configure gunicorn (or something) to wait until new processes load?

Just sending `kill -HUP` seems to be insufficient for the purpose. Requests which come before the new process loads seems to be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

`gunicorn` has a argument:

```
-t, --timeout.
```

Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, for me when there is a compute intensive workload in the server, gunicorn restart takes a lot of time to restart.

This gets the ports of gunicorn and kills the workers right away.

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -n -i | grep gunicorn | awk '{print $2}'`
```

and then restart

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
```